# How to update delay in AbstractScheduledService

Tags: java, service, guava, scheduler

I am implementing guava into a module inside myApp, I am having difficulty in understanding when the AbstractScheduledService works, my goal is make a service that runs from time to time, but I want to by code, set to run in different time intervals.
So my question is: How can I update the time interval in the delay between Iterations?

My Code so far

```
public class Service extends AbstractScheduledService {


public String id;
private int timeInterval;
private TimeUnit unit;
public boolean keepAsking;

/**
 *
 * @param newTimeInterval
 * @param newTimeUnit
 */
public void pauseAndUpdate(int newTimeInterval, TimeUnit newTimeUnit) throws Exception {
    this.shutDown();
    timeInterval = newTimeInterval;
    unit = newTimeUnit;
    keepAsking = true;
    this.startAndWait();
}

protected Scheduler scheduler() {
    System.out.println("Scheduling : "+ timeInterval + unit);
    return Scheduler.newFixedRateSchedule(0, timeInterval, unit);
}

public Service(int timeInterval,TimeUnit unit){
    super();
    id = "XPTO";
    this.timeInterval = timeInterval;
    this.unit = unit;
    keepAsking = true;
}

public void pauseAndUpdate(int newTimeInterval) throws Exception {

    pauseAndUpdate(newTimeInterval,this.unit);

}

@Override
protected void runOneIteration() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Running");
    if(!keepAsking) {
        stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'll want to change your `scheduler()` method to return a [`CustomScheduler`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.CustomScheduler.html). After each iteration, the service will ask the scheduler for the [delay](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.CustomScheduler.Schedule.html) before the next iteration.

Comment: yes, unfortunately we changed the way to run this.. from time to time, into on how many operations, it is way better to run if we consider high use of the API, I was trying to get an example on how it is implemented so I can check, what I was doing wrong. But anyway, problem solved. Thanks